# Unable to pass param on clicking button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller `models_controller.rb` as following:

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @models=["A","E","M","I"]
  end

  def get_config
    Rails.logger.info(params[:model_id])
    //some logic based on params[:model_id] value
  end
end
```

The corresponding list.html.erb is as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @models.each_with_index do |model, index| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= model %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "view", {:controller => :models, :action => :get_config, :model_id => index }, :method => :get %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each row of this table has a button, where upon clicking, I am passing the index of the element. But I am not been able to access it in the get_config method. Logger is printing an empty string. `routes.rb` is as follows:

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "models/list"
  get "models/get_config"

  get "models/list/:model_id" => "models#get_config"
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified. So `get "models/get_config"` is catching the request before `get "models/list/:model_id" => "models#get_config"`. Try changing the order to this:

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "models/list"
  get "models/list/:model_id" => "models#get_config"
  get "models/get_config"
end
```